# How to draw or display buttons on the X and Y position in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am new to android. I want to display buttons on the screen at particular x and y position.
I have an one Relative layout and i put background image to that relative layout now i want to create or draw buttons on that image at particular x and y position and that X and Y position are given by me through XML i have 5 X and Y position. i google a lot but not found any relative solutions every one says using AbsoluteLayout we can do that but i dont want to use AbsoluteLayout.

Please help me out.

Comment: You can try setting specific top and left margin values for each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or ;

```
RelativeLayout yourRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_1);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Params.leftMargin = 25;
Params.topMargin = 25;    

Button newButton = new Button(this);

yourRelativeLayout.addView(newButton, Params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to : **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams**

For Example :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Button button1 = new Button(this);
button1.setLayoutParams(Params);

Params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button1.getId());
Button button2 = new Button(this);
button2.setLayoutParams(Params);
```

I hope this answer help you...